# Print a pattern of text based on a line from an Excel file

Tags: python, beginner, python-2.x, excel, formatting

I started to learn Python not long ago to automate certain tasks I work on. I want to optimize a script I wrote that takes a line in an Excel file and prints a pattern of text based on this line's content. Here's an example of output from my code:

```
mgmt_cli add access-rule layer "network" position bottom name "thirdline" source.1 "Value1front" source.2 "Value2front" source.3 "x3front" destination "Dest1front" service "HTTP" track.type "Log" action "Accept"
```

How would you optimize this code?

Link to the example file (just click Valider et Télécharger le Fichier) http://dl.free.fr/hFlGmywIN
Link to full code : https://pastebin.com/CR5SXHRQ

```
import xlrd
import re
loc = ("Dir\StackoverflowExample.xlsx")

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc) 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 
sheet.cell_value(0, 0) 

# Extracting number of rows 

def CaseMulti(CellContent, CellName):
 #takes a cell and a string as parameters, prints a pattern like Cell.X ="string", X starts with 0 and ends at the number of line in the Cell
 case = str(CellContent)  
 x= re.split ("\s", case)   #splits the cell contents in a list using regex where space is the separator for the list's elements
 if name == CellContent:  # deals with the cell with spaces between objects no clue how it work but it does
  return "name " + '"{}"'.format(CellContent)
 else:
  s=0
  string =""
  anycells = ["any","Any", "ANY"]  # tests if the soure, destination or service has any ==> returns nothing
  if str(x[0]) in anycells :
   return " " 
  else:
   if len(x)==1:    # case where te cell has one line (or a word with no spaces)
    string= CellName + " " +'"{}"'.format(case)

   else:            # case where multilines/mutli spaces
    while s<len (x) :
     listelement = x[s]
     string = string + CellName+'.'+str(s+1)+ ' '  +'"{}"'.format(listelement)
     s=s+1

   return string

for numberofrows in range (5):

 print "Rule " + str (numberofrows)
 name= sheet.cell_value(numberofrows,1)
 source = sheet.cell_value(numberofrows,2)
 destination = sheet.cell_value(numberofrows,3)
 protocole = sheet.cell_value(numberofrows,4)
 log = sheet.cell_value(numberofrows,5)
 action = sheet.cell_value(numberofrows,6)
 #firewall = sheet.cell_value(numberofrows,7)

 try:
  print ("mgmt_cli add access-rule layer \"network\" position bottom " + str(CaseMulti(name,"name")) +  str(CaseMulti(source, " source")) + str(CaseMulti(destination, " destination")) +  str(CaseMulti(protocole, " service")) +   ' track.type "Log" ' + str(CaseMulti(action, " action")) )
 except :
  numberofrows +=1
```

Answer (score 1):

**STYLING**

According to [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), there are a few improvements to be made to your code:

- Imports: Your imports should go in alphabetical order
- Variable/Function Names: You should use `snake_case` instead of `camelCase`
- Parameter Names: This may just be how I view your code, but how your parameters are named look like your taking in objects. You should use lowercase variables for better readability.
- Spacing: You should use 4 spaces for each indent. For variable declaration and assignment, the `=` should be separated by a space on each side for readability, like so: `s=0` to `s = 0`.
- Main Guard: You should wrap any regular code in a [if '**name** == '**main**'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) guard, to make sure that the code is only being run when that file is the main file, and not being imported by anything.

**STRING FORMATTING**

All throughout your code, you put strings together using `+` and `.format`. Luckily there is an easier way, by putting an `f` before the string like so: `f"content here"`. This erases the need to have verbose `+` in your strings, and you no longer have to cast `int` to `str` with this method, you can just write the code in the brackets `{your code here}`.

Example:

`return "name " + '"{}"'.format(cell_content)`

to

`return f"name \"{cell_content}\""`

Here is the updated code:

```
import re
import xlrd

loc = ("Dir\StackoverflowExample.xlsx")

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc) 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 
sheet.cell_value(0, 0) 

# Extracting number of rows 

def case_multi(cell_content, cell_name):
    #takes a cell and a string as parameters, prints a pattern like Cell.X ="string", X starts with 0 and ends at the number of line in the Cell
    case = str(cell_content)  
    x = re.split ("\s", case)   #splits the cell contents in a list using regex where space is the separator for the list's elements
    if name == cell_content:  # deals with the cell with spaces between objects no clue how it work but it does
        return f"name \"{cell_content}\""
    else:
        s = 0
        string = "" 
    if str(x[0]).lower() == "any":
        return " " 
    else:
        if len(x) == 1: # case where the cell has one line (or a word with no spaces)
            string = f"{cell_name} \"{case}\""
        else: # case where multilines/mutli spaces
            while s < len(x):
                listelement = x[s]
                string += f"{cell_name}.{str(s + 1)} \"{listelement}\""
                s += 1

        return string

def main():

    for number_of_rows in range(5):

        print "Rule " + str(number_of_rows)
        name= sheet.cell_value(number_of_rows, 1)
        source = sheet.cell_value(number_of_rows, 2)
        destination = sheet.cell_value(number_of_rows, 3)
        protocole = sheet.cell_value(number_of_rows, 4)
        log = sheet.cell_value(number_of_rows, 5)
        action = sheet.cell_value(number_of_rows, 6)
        #firewall = sheet.cell_value(number_of_rows, 7)

        try:
            print ("mgmt_cli add access-rule layer \"network\" position bottom " + str(case_multi(name,"name")) +  str(case_multi(source, " source")) + str(case_multi(destination, " destination")) +  str(case_multi(protocole, " service")) +   ' track.type "Log" ' + str(case_multi(action, " action")) )
        except:
            number_of_rows += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: To be clear, PEP-8 specifies that indentation should be 4 spaces per level, not a TAB character. This is an important convention to follow, since indentation matters in Python.

Comment: @200_success Is a tab not already 4 spaces? I already had the clarification next to it I just assumed they were the same length

Comment: I would avoid any mention of "tab", since that just adds a possible misinterpretation: an ASCII character 9, and configuring your text editor or terminal to use 4-character-wide tabstops.

Answer (score -1):

It seems a main thing you need to learn about is `f-strings`

These are an update to the old `format` method.

```
print "Rule " + str (numberofrows)
```

becomes

```
print(f"Rule str(numberofrows)")
```

and

```
"name " + '"{}"'.format(CellContent)
```

becomes

```
f"name {CellContent}"
```

**NOTE** Python 3 uses () for print statements

It is also worth using a PEP8 checker (such as `black` - `pip install black`) to make your code more readable

---

You could also change things like

```
s=s+1
```

to

```
s += 1
```

---

Rather than saying

```
anycells = ["any","Any", "ANY"]  
if str(x[0]) in anycells
...
```

You could say

```
if str(x[0]).lower() == "any"
```

---

Are you sure this is your code?
This looks very much like Python 2 code which hasn't been used for over 6 years. I am curious why you would write something in Python 2 still? It seems odd to learn Python 2 as a new beginner

Comment: thank you for your input. Yes this is my real code and it's in python 2, last time I coded was in Turbo Pascal that's why it looks very old